# Error in phone Authentication Firebase in one device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My App having the Phone authentication method for user register and login to firebase is working fine for some devices but in one device it had send the verification SMS only the first time i checked it. After that ,I even deleted that account from firebase console but it is not sending any verfication code on registering that number again.

```
public class phone_no_verification extends AppCompatActivity {
ProgressBar verify_progress;
    TextInputEditText verify_edittext;
    TextInputLayout verify_textInput;
   String mverificationID;
FirebaseAuth auth;
   static  String TAG;
SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_no_verification);
        verify_progress = findViewById(R.id.verify_progress);
        verify_edittext = findViewById(R.id.verify_edittext);
        verify_textInput = findViewById(R.id.verify_textinputLayout);



        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //getting Intent mobile number
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mobile = intent.getStringExtra("mobile_no");
        sendVerificationcode(mobile);



        //Entering code manually
        findViewById(R.id.verify_Button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String code = verify_edittext.getText().toString().trim();
                if(code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6){
                    verify_textInput.setError("Enter Valid code");
                }
                else{
                verifyVerificationCode(code);}
            }
        });

    }

    private void sendVerificationcode(String mobile) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber
                ("+91" + mobile,60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,mcallbacks);
    }

    //callback to detect verification status
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mcallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
mverificationID = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + phoneAuthCredential);

            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

if(code != null){
    verify_edittext.setText(code);
    verifyVerificationCode(code);
}
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(phone_no_verification.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };


    private void verifyVerificationCode(String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mverificationID,code);

        //signing user
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(phone_no_verification.this
            , new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                  if(task.isSuccessful()){
Intent intent = new Intent(phone_no_verification.this, Basic_activity.class);
                      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

startActivity(intent);
                      sp = getSharedPreferences("login",MODE_PRIVATE);
                      sp.edit().putBoolean("isAutheticated",true).apply();
                  }
                  else{
                      String message = "Somthing is wrong, we will fix it soon...";
                      if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException){
                          message = "Invalid code Entered..";
                      }
                      else if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
                          message = "User Already Exists";
                      }

Toast.makeText(phone_no_verification.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  }


                }
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: can't help without some code

Comment: is it not sending the code and not registering the phone? or is it not sending the code but auto-verifying and creating a phone account?

Comment: It is neither sending the code nor registering that particular phone